Send Cloud-CDN-Cookie (Google) along with Ajax Request in OpenSeaDragon
I am using Cloud CDN with signed cookies to serve images -- so I need to send the Cloud-CDN-Cookie along with the request for the images. I have been able to verify that the cookie is created and exists.
How do I instruct OpenSeaDragon to send the Cloud-CDN-Cookie to Google Cloud CDN?
I tried these settings in OpenSeaDragon:
useCredentials: true,
crossOriginPolicy: 'use-credentials',

Thanks!
